# Open link from XPages RTF field

Tags: browser, xpages, lotus-notes, rtf

I have a document created in Lotus Notes client, with a RTF field. In that field I created a link hotspot in it that has to open a document in a shared unit of my net. It works fine when I click from Lotus Notes client. But when I open the same document using an XPages it doesn't work. When I click from XPages it do anything. Of course when I try open from XPages I have access to that shared unit.

tks, 
[image: XPages link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons the browser rejects the file:// URL.

In Google Chrome you can allow file URLs if Chrome is starsted with a special parameter.

Internet Explorer rejects the file URLs for certain security zones.

[Firefox rejects the file URLs too](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work).

Comment: Hello Per, 
I have tried with IE, downloading the security zone and in this case it works fine. Do you know the parameter fro Chrome?? and for Firefox, Do you know other way to do that without install an extension??
Tks,

Comment: Try launching Chrome with this parameter: --allow-file-access-from-files